# Promise in for loop returns wrong value

Tags: node.js, promise

This might be a silly question. Below is a stripped down version of my code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { // objects.length = 10
    CuQuery.count().then(function(result){
      Cucount = result;
      console.log("i value = "+i);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
}
```

In console, I get `i value = 10`, 10 times as output.
I expected it to print value 1 to 10. What am I doing wrong ? or Is it the correct behavior ?

Comment: It is correct behavior, that is how async works

Comment: Your passed function will be called a long time (some ms) after the iteration is done. At this moment ```i``` has the value`= 10. This behaviour is totally correct.

Comment: Promises within loops is very tricky, in my opinion better use `async.map` or `async.mapSeries`.

Comment: Thanks Ananth and Frank Roth for the clarification. Answers from the the original question (of which it is a duplicate) helped a little understand the problem.